# apply mixed colors to actor libgdx

Tags: colors, libgdx, actor

I am developing game in that many of balloons having different colors. I am applying color to them dynamically.

Now the problem is I am using

```
public Color(float r,
 float g,
 float b,
 float a)
```

Constructor, sets the components of the color
Parameters:
r - the red component
g - the green component
b - the blue component
a - the alpha component

copied from color document

here when I am using Color constructor by passing value like

```
color = new Color(1,0,0,1);
```

it works,,

but when I am passing values to get mixed color like

```
 color = new Color(123,118,221,1);
```

this time this is not working....

please identify the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor expects floats values between 0 and 1 so divide ur integer RGB by 255 to get the answer (0-255 is the range for rgb).

Color = new Color(123/255f,118/255f,221/255f,1);

this solves ur problem

Comment: while this is correct, Google has twice directed me here when I've been looking for the name of the `lerp` function in _Color.java_